# DB-API x database module

Tags: python, database, python-db-api

What is a DB-API (Python) and what is a database module and how do they interact ?

I have a TCC project and I need to understand the difference and the purpose of these terms. I thought DB-API was, for example, a driver like psycopg2 but psycopg2 is a driver and has another purpose. If I'm wrong, correct me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DB-API is a specification](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) that SQL database modules written in Python adhere to.

- `psycopg2` is a DB-API compliant module for PostgreSQL,
- `mysqlclient` is a DB-API compliant module for MySQL,
- `cx_Oracle` is a DB-API compliant module for Oracle,

etc.